# How to properly debug and determine javascript/ajax root cause of a js error in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, debugging, ie-developer-tools

Site (url) is here: http://www.icrm.org/career-opportunities/

This shows a table in which the column headers are clickable (they sort) and the column **Career Title** entries are all clickable - they lead to a details screen that shows more.

This works well (formatting issues aside) in all browsers except IE

What is bizarre is that in IE only the first link in the list of Titles does't work (Electronic Records Manager Structured). Yet you can see the call is identical to every other title when you mouse over it. All the other links work fine.

When the list is re-sorted the problem "follows" the link in question NOT staying associated with the (new) first link.

This rules out **positionally** as the root cause however I've also changed the title of the item in question enough times to eliminate anything that the text contains.

My question is where do I go from here? Every platform I use for development the problem doesn't manifest.

Comment: Well, I would start checking these [23 markup errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icrm.org%2Fcareer-opportunities%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), then check the console, you have a few warnings.

Comment: Look at the console: `"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getAttribute': object is null or undefined 
api.js, line 421 character 4"`

Answer (score 2):

So if you open this up in IE dev tools (hit F12) you can monitor the network traffic and see what is going on behind the scenes. When you click "Electronic Records Manager Structured" the following executes successfully: javascript:fetchRemoteData(null,"&column=Title&rowID=1114").  This results in a successful network request and response containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<JobPostings columns="19" method="DisplayAJobPost" rows="1">
   <JobPosting row="0">
      <ID>1114</ID>
      <ApprovedPublic>Y</ApprovedPublic>
      <Status>Approved</Status>
      <Title>Electronic Records Manager Structured</Title>
      <Location>Rosemead, California United States Of America</Location>
      <Company>Southern California Edison</Company>
      <CRMQualifications>CRM Preferred</CRMQualifications>
      <Requirements/>
      <Description>Highly-motivated; like challenge; &#13;
collaborative; committed to delivering &#13;
high quality workÉ Did we describe &#13;
you? Read onÉ&#13;
 &#13;
Southern California Edison is one of &#13;
the nation?s largest investor-owned &#13;
electric utilities. We are an industry &#13;
leader that is designing new and &#13;
innovative ways to meet our &#13;
...
```

This too me looks to all be behaving normally and correctly.  However, when your application then goes to try and display this on the page:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference
File: api.js, Line: 421, Column: 4.

and

XML5617: Illegal XML character. Line: 14, Column 18

I suspect this is because the XML that you are returning for that specific record is invalid.  Start there, hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you except it doesn't answer why IE and not any other browser. The XML is parsed and assembled server side and validated so what changes mid stream (and/or why) that causes this to occur between the server and the client? 

I'll do a convert everything to ascii server side and resave the document (thought I started there...) and see if that helps. 

Appreciate the debugging -- thank you!

Comment: I am not an expert on XML parsing in browsers, however it would not surprise me at all if different browsers obey different XML standards (as they have done for years with other W3C standards)  This might explain the behavior holy occurring in IE.  The problem is definitely happening in your XML parsing, so that would be the best place to start debugging.  Perhaps another post on here might serve you well with information specifically about why your XML is failing etc.

Comment: New information -- as the listing change it **consistently** drops the **first** entry and yet if you resort the entries they are no longer in that order and the entry that was first still has the issue. 

So based on that it is **not** a data specific issue. (I've tried scrubbing the data time and time again not he back end to be pure ascii only). 

It *appears** to be a positional issue or something that clogs a cache perhaps. simply send the (pre) formatted block instead?)

Comment: Way past the level of effort it is worth to fix it -- it's slated for replacement. (Why do JS manipulation of the data when I can simply generate everything I need server side and simply send a (pre) formatted block to the client to display?

Comment: I agree with that strategy to a point, however it can be easy to slip into bad habits when you do formatting server-side as it violates the practice of separating form from function and leads to unmaintainable code and difficult debugging.

That's interesting though - I am surprised that it is not a data issue.  I would have to take a closer look at your server-side implementation to provide more insight.  That said, it could be that the XML parsing problem is a symptom of a larger problem and not the problem itself - that could be trickier to pin down.

Comment: You might also look into using JSON as opposed to XML for your data transfer.  It is cleaner, lighter, and has (I believe) better parsing support in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of this but it seems there are some not compatible characters returned in you response for **Electronic Records Manager Structured**. Can you check if you don't have any character which does not fall under [this given charset](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets), if you do have any invalid charater then your element returned from `techanoReq.responseXML.documentElement` will be null.

Comment: We use com.jamesmurty.utils.XMLBuilder server side to assemble the XML -- we've used the exact same library for years processing MILLIONS of transactions for Blackberry messaging in the courier space -- doubt we could get an illegal character through even if we tried.  

Not saying you're wrong -- just trying to figure out how I could be wrong myself here.